How to hide Y-axis in antd charts
I want to hide de Y-axis from Line component in Ant design charts (React)
My current versions are:

React: 18.3.1
antd: 5.19.3
ant-design/charts: 2.1.2


I am using the module
import { Line } from '@ant-design/plots';
With this setting object:
{
  data: datasets || [],
  xField: 'label',
  yField: 'value',
  width: data.hasLegends ? 1300 : 1600,
  seriesField: 'type',
  color,
  smooth: true,
  xAxis: {
    label: {
      style: {
        fill: NEUTRAL_BLACK,
        fontSize: 12,
      },
      formatter: upperCase,
    },
  },
  yAxis: false,
  position: 'right',
  legend: false,
  theme: {
    styleSheet: {
      fontFamily: 'Foundry Monoline Extra Bold',
    },
  },
  label: {
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'Foundry Monoline Medium',
      fontSize: 12,
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
    transform: [{ type: 'overlapDodgeY'}],
    textBaseline: 'bottom',
    textAlign: 'center',
    formatter: (text, record) => {
      let value = '';
      if ('accounting_type' in record) {
        switch (record.type) {
          case TYPE_REVENUE:
            value = Formatter.toCurrency(record.value);
            break;
          case TYPE_EXPENSE:
            value = `-${Formatter.toCurrency(record.value)}`;
            // this prevents an overlap of "$0.00" and "-$0.00"
            if (record.value == 0 && datasets.length === TWO_VALUES_PER_MONTH) value = ``;
            break;
          default:
            value = Formatter.toCurrency(record.value);
            break;
        }
      } else {
        value = Formatter.toCurrency(record.value);
      }
      // Retornar el valor formateado como moneda
      return value;
    },
  },
  point: {
    shape: 'circle',
    size: 3,
    style: {
      r: 4,
    },
  },
  tooltip: false,
  interactions: [
    {
      type: 'marker-active',
    },
  ],
  shapeField: 'smooth',
}

I have even tried this setting from documentation, but it doesn't work as I expected
axis: {
    x: {},
    y: {},
  }

In this documentation there isn't a mention from y-axis hide: https://ant-design-charts.antgroup.com/en/options/plots/component/axis
I really appreciate any feedback ;)

use null instead of empty object.
const config = {
    ...
    axis: {
        x: null,
        y: null
    },
};


<Line {...config} />

